# JQuery Dialog document ready

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

When will `$(document).ready()` run if it is placed in a separate view which is loaded as a part of dialog control? Will it follow the pattern of running after the view is fully loaded inside the dialog called by the parent page?

Comment: It runs when the *page* is fully loaded.  JQuery knows nothing about the View.

Comment: The script will only be loaded later. So you mean this will run after that dialog.cshtml is loaded inside the dialog of parent control?

Comment: If you know the page is already loaded when you load the script, then don't put it inside `document.ready`.  That event only fires once, when the DOM finishes loading.

Comment: @user1826777 it will be called immediately.

Comment: I am reusing part of script from another full page which has script wrapped inside document.ready. Not sure where to put this script if I have to send this new page only during dialog load.

Comment: what is inside you'r document.ready?

Comment: It has initialization code for another popup. Making that popup ready etc? Do we have some control.ready kind of thing where we trigger the script after that part of html control is populated

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready method means to run any javascript only after DOM (Document Object Model / All the elements of page) loaded successfully.

So logically when you'll put any javascript code under $(document).ready() it'll run after all the elements of page will load.